# Buliding asmJit Example with Cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to build a example project based on asmJit.

I have the following setup 
AsmTest

- main.cpp
- CmakeLists.txt
- libs

  - asmjit (inside is the CmakeList.txt from the github repo).
  - CMakeLists.txt (content: add_subdirectory(asmjit))
- build

The content of my first CmakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(asmJitTest)

add_subdirectory(libs)
include_directories(${asmJitTest_SOURCE_DIR} ${asmJitTest_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/asmjit/src)
add_executable(JitTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(JitTest asmjit)
```

I can sucessfully build this project, getting a visual studio solution.
But if I try to run it in visual studios, I get various "unresolved external errors" like this for example.

```
1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct asmjit::X86RegData   
    const asmjit::x86RegData" (?x86RegData@asmjit@@3UX86RegData@1@B)    main.obj    JitTest
```

I dont  understand why I get linking errors.
I am new to cmake, and this whole bulding from scratch process.
Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compile asmjit as a dynamically linked library, you can do that by simply including its `CMakeLists.txt` within your cmake script:

```
Set(ASMJIT_DIR "/relative/dir/to/your/asmjit")
Include("${ASMJIT_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt")

# AsmJit should have already taken care of include directories, if you
# are not sure you can add it, but shouldn't be necessary.
Include_Directories(${ASMJIT_DIR})

# Then in your target you should be able to use:
Target_Link_Libraries(YourTarget asmjit ${ASMJIT_DEPS})
```

Alternatively, and I found this to be much more reliable for embedding asmjit as a static library, embed the whole asmjit in your project. AsmJit has a built-in support for that:

```
# Tell asmjit that it will be embedded.
Set(ASMJIT_EMBED TRUE)
Add_Definitions(-DASMJIT_STATIC)

Set(ASMJIT_DIR "/relative/dir/to/your/asmjit")
Include("${ASMJIT_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt")

# If you add a library / executable, include asmjit sources.
Add_Executable(YourTarget main.cpp ${ASMJIT_SRC})

# You still have to include asmjit dependencies.
Target_Link_Libraries(YourTarget ${ASMJIT_DEPS})
```

The second approach has one big advantage over building asmjit dynamically or statically, that it can be embedded into a dynamically linked library this way without having problems under Linux and all platforms that require you to use `-fPIC`, because cmake by default doesn't put `-fPIC` into static library builds, but this would be for a longer discussion and it's not really related to your question.

Comment: Thanks I compiled it as static libary and now it works.

Comment: I also used the static version, and it works. Thanks for this great little SO gem (that I found only after days of struggling with CMAKE)!

Answer (score 1):

asmjit's CMakeList.txt contains the following code:

```
set(ASMJIT_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}" CACHE PATH "Location of 'asmjit'")
set(ASMJIT_TEST       ${ASMJIT_TEST}              CACHE BOOL "Build 'asmjit' test applications")
set(ASMJIT_EMBED      ${ASMJIT_EMBED}             CACHE BOOL "Embed 'asmjit' library (no targets)")
set(ASMJIT_STATIC     ${ASMJIT_STATIC}            CACHE BOOL "Build 'asmjit' library as static")
set(ASMJIT_SANITIZE   ${ASMJIT_SANITIZE}          CACHE STRING "Build with sanitizers: 'address', 'undefined', etc...")
set(ASMJIT_BUILD_X86  ${ASMJIT_BUILD_X86}         CACHE BOOL "Build X86 backends (X86 and X86_64)")
```

This info will allow you to do the following in your own CMakeList.txt

```
set(ASMJIT_STATIC TRUE)
add_subdirectory(asmjit)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} asmjit::asmjit)
```